# What is the purpose of "illegal" cards?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

In Yu-Gi-Oh, there are several cards with "You cannot use this card in a duel", such as Chimaera, The Master of Beasts:

[image: Chimaera, The Master of Beasts]

Since this card cannot be used in a duel, what exactly is the point of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be a number of different reasons for cards existing.  In the point of Chimaera, [it was a prize card from the 2007 World Championships](https://yugipedia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_World_Championship_2007_prize_cards).

It's not uncommon for a TCG to have official cards that are unplayable in any format.

- Promotional cards
- Special cards given out as championship prizes, similar to a trophy
- Extremely limited print run cards

Looking at [this link](https://yugipedia.com/wiki/Limitation_text), it appears that all of the cards that have that text are either promotional cards (see [Set Sail for the Kingdom](https://yugipedia.com/wiki/Set_Sail_for_The_Kingdom)) or cards given out as prizes for tournaments.